# Providing typescript declaration file for external lib with Nx

Tags: nrwl-nx

This question has been asked and answered many different ways on Stack overflow and I think I've tried them all. This question is specific to getting it to work using @nrwl/nx.

The specific error is

```
TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'libxmljs2-xsd'. '/Users/xyz/hpxml-gen/node_modules/libxmljs2-xsd/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/libxmljs2-xsd` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'libxmljs2-xsd';`
```

I've tried unsuccessfully:

1. Creating a global.d.ts file with `declare module 'libxmljs2-xsd'` in it.
2. Create index.d.ts file with `declare module 'libxmljs2-xsd'` and tried putting it at the root of the Nx lib, inside `src` and inside `src/lib`. None of those locations worked.
3. Modifying tsconfig.lib.json inside the root dir: `"include": ["**/*.ts", "**/*.d.ts"]`. I've also tried `"include": ["**/*.ts", "index.d.ts"]`
4. Created `types/index.d.ts` at root and in the root tsconfig.base.json added `"typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types", "./types"]`

I realize I can set `"noImplicitAny": false` but don't want to do that and lose a lot of the value of typescript.

I've spent a day on this thinking there has to be something simple I'm missing. I've searched stack overflow, all of the GitHub tickets and their documentation. Does anyone know how this works in Nx?

Comment: Did you solve this situation, if so, can you provide a solution?

Comment: I'm able to achieve this by setting `"esModuleInterop": true,` in `tsconfig.base.json` in project root folder and add `module-name.d.ts` in the project root folder.

Comment: OMG @Zesky thanks I already tried all the possible combinations for paths 

Comment: Well, I'm also stuck on this problem. I'm creating a custom theme with MUI, I created a lib in util/types/theme.d.ts e till now I could find a way to make it work across my apps (micro-frontends)

Answer (score -2):

you should add the `declaration: true` inside your `compilerOptions` object declared inside your tsconfig.json file.

Refer the official docs for more info: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#declaration

Comment: This is how you output .d.ts for your libraries during compilation. @Jeff is asking about the opposite problem - how to define .d.ts for already build libraries that do not have such. Therefore my downvoting.